# Auto scroll ONLY child component, NOT parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

See: https://jsfiddle.net/wh6r4ybe/42/

```
const historyEndRef = useRef(null);

const scrollToBottom = () => {
  historyEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
};

useEffect(() => {
  scrollToBottom();
});
```

I'm hoping to auto-scroll to the bottom of the blue SubComponent on render using the above method, but the result scrolls to the bottom of the red parent Component as well.

How do I avoid scrolling in the parent component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `block` property with value `end`:

```js
historyEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: 'end' });
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shrys/zL8psx7u/)

Comment: not work when parent will be at top in this case both will scroll down, what to do if anyone  want to scroll only child not parent when parent at the top and child at the bottom???